# Can a plane curve have an odd number of vertices?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

The celebrated Four-Vertex Theorem says that the number of vertices of a plane curve must be at least 4.  Must it be, more specifically, an *even* number at least 4?

Here's why that seems to me that it should be the case: Suppose you have a closed curve $\gamma(s)$ parametrized by arclength, with length $L$.  Assume WLOG that you parametrize such that your starting and ending point is not a stationary point of curvature (if no such point exists, you're looking at a circle...let's consider $\infty$ to be an even number).  Since $\kappa(s)$ is smooth and periodic, its derivative at $0$ and at $L$ must be the same, and that derivative isn't zero.  So $\kappa'(s)$ must change sign evenly many times on $[0,L]$, hence evenly many vertices.

QED, maybe?  The thing that makes me suspicious is that, in discussion of the Four-Vertex Theorem, I've not seen this result stated.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Sounds fine, and pretty obvious. Maybe that's why it isn't mentioned explicitly.

Comment: If you only define vertex points to be point where the first derivative of the curvature vanishes, it's possible that $\kappa'(s)=0$ without $\kappa'$ changing sign around $s$